# How to send File to offline user in xmpp smack or asmack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I tried both smack and asmack.I am able to login,register and send message and send file also.but problem is when i am sending file to offline user i am getting (service unavailable 503 ) error.how can i send file to offline user using smack or asmack ...if not possible with smack and asmack then what is alternate way ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. The only solution I could think of, was to develop an upload service, that allows the user to upload a file and generates an url, where the file can be downloaded.

I run the service on the jabber server and I am using the same credentials for login.

1. the first app uploads the file, and receives a download url which is the "secret"
2. it sends the url to the other client using a custom protocoll extension, the other client downloads the file if he chooses to do so

You may customize your protocol to decide when to remove the file of the upload server.

This technique also has the advantage, that you can share or forward downloads without wasting bandwidth on client side.

But I am not really satisified with my solution, as I have to develop an own service. Would be great if is was part of the XMPP and already implemented on a jabber open fire server.